# Column X.StaffName is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Got this error message:

> Column 'X.StaffName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT StaffID, StaffName, SUM(STRStaffPts) AS STR_StaffPts, SUM(WDRStaffPts) AS WDR_StaffPts
FROM (
SELECT [PlayerId] AS StaffID, ''AS StaffName, [PointsEarned] AS STRStaffPts, 0 AS WDRStaffPts
FROM [C_STR_StaffSession1] WHERE ([EndTime] between '2019-12-02 03:00:00.000' AND '2019-12-03 23:59:59.000')
Union ALL
SELECT [Legacy Staff ID] AS StaffID, ''AS StaffName, 0 AS STRStaffPts, [Points Earned] AS WDRStaffPts
FROM [C_STR_StaffSession2]
WHERE (CAST([Gaming Date] AS DATETIME)+CAST(CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), [End time] / 100)+ ':' + CONVERT(varchar(10), [End time] % 100)) AS TIME) between '2019-12-02 03:00:00.000' AND '2019-12-03 23:59:59.000')
Union ALL
SELECT [Legacy Staff ID] AS StaffID, [First Name] AS StaffName, 0 AS STRStaffPts, 0 AS WDRStaffPts FROM [C_STR_StaffRecord]) AS X GROUP BY StaffID
```

Comment: Use `GROUP BY StaffID, StaffName` instead of `GROUP BY StaffID`

Comment: Then remove it from the list, apply an aggregate function to it or include it in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Is there a question there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You group only by StaffID while selecting StaffName as well. This should be correct:

```
  SELECT StaffID, StaffName, SUM(STRStaffPts) AS STR_StaffPts, SUM(WDRStaffPts) AS WDR_StaffPts
    FROM (
    SELECT [PlayerId] AS StaffID, ''AS StaffName, [PointsEarned] AS STRStaffPts, 0 AS WDRStaffPts
    FROM [C_STR_StaffSession1] WHERE ([EndTime] between '2019-12-02 03:00:00.000' AND '2019-12-03 23:59:59.000')
    Union ALL
    SELECT [Legacy Staff ID] AS StaffID, ''AS StaffName, 0 AS STRStaffPts, [Points Earned] AS WDRStaffPts
    FROM [C_STR_StaffSession2]
    WHERE (CAST([Gaming Date] AS DATETIME)+CAST(CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), [End time] / 100)+ ':' + CONVERT(varchar(10), [End time] % 100)) AS TIME) between '2019-12-02 03:00:00.000' AND '2019-12-03 23:59:59.000')
    Union ALL
    SELECT [Legacy Staff ID] AS StaffID, [First Name] AS StaffName, 0 AS STRStaffPts, 0 AS WDRStaffPts FROM [C_STR_StaffRecord]) AS X GROUP BY StaffID, StaffName
```

Comment: thank you so much. one last thing. how can i ommit of those staffname who doesnt have record in table [C_STR_StaffSession1] and [C_STR_StaffSession2]. thanks again